# Travis CI & iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, travis-ci

Did anyone managed to get [Travis CI](https://magnum.travis-ci.com/) to deploy the app on iTunesConnect? I have read tons of articles and tried them without success.

My closest bet was this article:

[Continuously Delivering iOS Beta Builds Automated with Travis CI](http://code.oursky.com/continuously-delivering-ios-builds-automated-with-travis-ci/)

They didn't provide info that you need to install [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) in order to work, so pay attention if you go this way.

The main problem however is the fact that I do not have Crittercism or HockeyApp accounts, however the python script want them from me and no matter if I do not provide them or provide fake it fails later as it actually tries to do something with them.

Other thing that I come across is:

[Automated iOS beta distribution using Travis CI and Testflight](https://medium.com/ios-apprentice/automated-ios-app-beta-distribution-30855d77931a)

which is essentially written on top of [Deploy an iOS app to testflight using Travis CI](https://gist.github.com/johanneswuerbach/5559514). The problem here is that they deploy to TestFlight app instead of iTunesConnect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking into the ruby gem [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools).  We have been using it for quite some time and it has definitely saved us hours of problems related to deploying to iTunesConnect.  I haven't used TravisCI before but from [this blog post](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-12-10-xcode-72-is-ready) I know they support `fastlane`.  The community is great and [@KrauseFX](https://twitter.com/KrauseFx?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) is awesome at answering any questions you might have.  He even uses TravisCI to build the `fastlane` tools!